# "Prove that for any proposition $Ax$, $(∃x)(Ax) \iff \lnot(∀x)(\lnot Ax)$"

Tags: logic

I have been trying to solve the question as mentioned above and I have failed to so do. Please provide me a solution.

Comment: What have you tried? What logical rules are you allowed to use?

Comment: See the answer to similar [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3178621/show-neg-forall-x-phi-vdash-exists-x-neg-phi-using-an-nd-derivation).

Comment: @ZeroXLR This is my 1st post on logic. I am new in logic. I would like to request you to use very basic logical rules and please solve.

Comment: Please, provide details about the proof system you are asked to use : Natural Deduction ?

Comment: Natural Deduction

Comment: @user1942348 I noticed you have approved of Dominic's edit. Still, I want to remind you it's highly recommended to include the question per se in the body.  As the main function of titles is to grab people's attention, it is not meant to be the first sentence of your question. The question body should not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: In order to prove anything at all, you need some rules of inference, and perhaps also some axioms.  We do not know the set-up in your course or your textbook, so we cannot answer this question.  (Indeed, "Natural Deduction" is done differently in different texts; it is not just one thing.) I recommend you ask your instructor for help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all for a formula $\varphi(x)$ we have

$\exists x\varphi(x) \iff \bigvee_a{\varphi(a)}$

and

$\forall x\varphi(x)\iff\bigwedge_a{\varphi(a)}$

In your case

$\neg\exists x\varphi(x) \iff \neg\bigvee_a{\varphi(a)} \iff \bigwedge_a{\neg\varphi(a)} \iff \forall x\neg\varphi(x)$

The above follows from the de morgan rules

Finally negating again gives

$\exists x\varphi(x) \iff \neg\neg\exists x\varphi(x) \iff \neg\forall x\neg\varphi(x)$

You need to make it a bit more formal but thats the idea